# Can I safely drop my table from schema 1?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sql-insert, ddl

**oracle**

In schema A I created a table called "apples" with data.

In Schema B I created a copy of table "apples" from schema 1 using

```
create table apples as select * from schemaA.apples
```

My question is, now that I have schema B up and running. Can I drop/delete my schemaA.apples? There is no direct link between the tables correct?

Or if I drop schemaA.apples will schemaB.apples get runied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There is no direct link between the tables correct?

Correct. You have two different tables, that are not related. You just copied data from one table to another at a given point in time.

> Or if I drop schemaA.apples will schemaB.apples get runied?

No, there is no risk that it will impact the other table. Again, data was copied, and tables are independent.

Side note: the `create table ... as select ...` syntax (aka *CTAS*) just copies the data and the structure, but not the related objects like primary keys, constraints, indexes, sequences. You might want to check these objects, and recreate them too to the new schema.

Comment: interesting, I didnt know that. thank you for that tip.